# NSMenu -- deleting items from menu while looping over items in menu

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, osx-lion, nsmenu

Can I write code like the following? It seems to work, but I want to make sure that it is allowed/safe:

```
// menu is a NSMenu*
for (NSMenuItem *item in [menu itemArray]) {
    if (some condition) {
        [menu removeItem:item];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't immediately throw an exception (as modifying an array directly when enumerating it does) then it's probably okay. `NSMenu` may be giving you a copy of its internal array (assuming it's keeping its items in an `NSArray`).

For guaranteed safety, however, you might like to do this in two steps. Create another array to hold the items for removal, then enumerate *that* and do the removal:

```
NSMutableArray * itemsToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];
for( NSMenuItem *item in [menu itemArray] ){
    if( some condition ){
        [itemsToRemove addObject:item];
    }
}

for( NSMenuItem * item in itemsToRemove ){
    [menu removeItem:item];
}
```

Comment: The last step can be shortened to [menu removeObjectsInArray:itemsToRemove].

Comment: @Martin: I don't believe that `NSMenu` has any such method.

Comment: You could just do it in one loop using `for (NSMenuItem* item in [[[menu itemArray] copy] autorelease])`. (Drop the autorelease if using ARC.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:
if you care about memory and dont want to create a secondary array use this:

```
for (int i = menu.itemArray.count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if( some condition for index i ){
        [menu removeItemAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```